# What happened after "Batman: The Dark Knight Returns"?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, dark-knight-returns-2012

Has there been a comic or a movie detailing the events of Part 2 of "Batman: The Dark Knight Returns"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dark Knight Strikes Again was published in 2001, and Dark Knight Returns III: The Master Race [electric boogaloo] was published in 2015. The Dark Knight Returns: The Last Crusade, a prequel series, is set to release this year.

You can read more about these on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns?wprov=sfsi1).